# No returns from a function which contains getAttribute

Tags: javascript, getattribute

I am trying to display the value of the button, but nothing shows up in the console when I press the buttons.

I am missing something and I can't figure it out.

```
 const allButtons = document.querySelector("[data-buttons]");

    Array.from(allButtons).forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let userPick = button.getAttribute("[data-pick]");
            console.log(userPick);
        });
    });
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: `getAttribute("data-pick")` without square brackets

Comment: `querySelector` only returns `null` or the first element found not a list that can be turned into an array so you end up with an empty array when using `Array.from`, you probably meant to use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If You have more then one button you need to use `querySelectorAll`

```js
 const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-buttons]");

    Array.from(allButtons).forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let userPick = button.getAttribute("data-pick");
            console.log(userPick);
        });
    });
```

```html
<button data-buttons="1" data-pick="1"> 1</button>
<button data-buttons="2" data-pick="2"> 2</button>
<button data-buttons="3" data-pick="3"> 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly loop over the Nodelist returned by `querySelectorAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-buttons]").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let userPick = button.getAttribute("data-pick");
    console.log(userPick);
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-buttons="1" data-pick="1"> 1</button>
<button data-buttons="2" data-pick="2"> 2</button>
<button data-buttons="3" data-pick="3"> 3</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `dataset` object in order to read `data-` related attributes, like this

```
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-buttons]");

Array.from(allButtons).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let userPick = button.dataset.pick;
        console.log(userPick);
    });
});
```

Comment: This code will not loop through all buttons, but only one.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the following commented code:

```js
// USE "querySelectorAll" INSTEAD OF "querySelector" TO ACTUALLY GET AN ARRAY-LIKE (NodeList) RESULT.
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-buttons]");

// YOU CAN DIRECTLY USE "forEach" ON A NodeList INSTANCE.
allButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    // "getAttribute" NEEDS ATTRIBUTE NAME AS INPUT WITHOUT "[]".
    // YOU CAN USE "e.target" INSTEAD OF "button" HERE.
    const userPick = target.getAttribute("data-pick");
    console.log(userPick);
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-buttons data-pick="A">Button A</button>
<button data-buttons data-pick="B">Button B</button>
<button data-buttons data-pick="C">Button C</button>
<button data-buttons data-pick="D">Button D</button>
<button data-buttons data-pick="E">Button E</button>
```